# Rails 5.0.2 - unable to get data from many-many relationship models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am stuck at getting data in `development.sqlite3` from 3 tables that have many-to-many relationship. I can get the courses that belong to a given location or category but it does not work the way around.

I followed the way I was taught in my class but I think the models might have missed some constraints.

Anyone please takes a look and gives me some suggestion. Thank you so much!

This is my `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
end

create_table "categories_courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "course_id",   null: false
    t.integer "category_id", null: false
end

create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
end

create_table "courses_locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "course_id",   null: false
    t.integer "location_id", null: false
end

create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "address"
end
```

I want to get the locations or the categories that associate with a given course. Then I added the relationships in the `models` like below:

```
# Category model
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :courses, join_table: 'categories_courses'
end

# Location model
class Location < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :courses, join_table: 'courses_locations'
end

# Course model
class Course < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :locations, join_table: 'courses_locations'
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, join_table: 'categories_courses'
end
```

Then in `courses_controller.rb`, I get the locations and categories like this:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_course, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def categories
        @course = Course.find params[:id]
        @categories = @course.categories
    end

    def locations
        @course = Course.find params[:id]
        @locations = @course.locations
    end

    private

    def set_course
        @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Finally I display data in `html.erb` file like this:

```
<% course.categories.each {|category| puts category.title + ' '} %>
<% course.locations.each {|location| puts location.address + ' '} %>
```

I am so sorry for putting lots of codes here, but I should provide enough information to examine the code.

Update:

I have this in `route.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :locations
  resources :categories
  resources :courses
end
```

I have edited the code as everyone's suggestions but it still prints nothing. I notice the query is correct but there is a warning in `rails s` console:

```
User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 35], ["LIMIT", 1]]
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing an argument to force an association to reload is now deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Please call `reload` on the result collection proxy instead. (called from block in _app_views_courses_index_html_erb___1034719630_104325280 at c:/Users/lovea/RubymineProjects/YourCourse/app/views/courses/index.html.erb:41)
Category Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categories_courses" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_courses"."category_id" WHERE "categories_courses"."course_id" = ?  [["course_id", 4]]
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? You cant get categories/locations to given course? What Rails version is this? `course.categories(course.id)` what is this suppose to do? Shouldnt it be just `@course.categories`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you probably need to add the option `join_table`

```
# Category model
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :courses, join_table: "categories_courses"
end

# Location model
class Location < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :courses, join_table: "courses_locations"
end

# Course model
class Course < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :locations, join_table: "courses_locations"
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, join_table: "categories_courses"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the associations should be working. I have tried it myself and got it working in the console. It might be that the issue you are having with `routing` perhaps.

Also, in the view, instead of:

```
<% course.categories(course.id).each {|category| puts category.title + ' '} %>
<% course.locations(course.id).each {|location| puts location.address + ' '} %>
```

You could:

```
<% course.categories.each {|category| puts category.title + ' '} %>
<% course.locations.each {|location| puts location.address + ' '} %>
```

Because the association is already there without the need to pass the id.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily create a view for many to many with  collecion checkboxes

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:course_id, Course.all, :id, :title) do |b| %>


   <div class="collection-check-box">
     <%= b.check_box %>
     <%= b.label %>

     <%end%>

     <%= f.submit 'add course to location', class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<%end%>
```